# Jackson serializes empty guava table as {"empty": true} instead of {}

Tags: serialization, jackson, guava, guava-table

I'm trying to serialize and deserialize an empty guava Table<R, C, V> object. The behavior I would expect is something like `"table": {}`, but what I'm getting is `"table": {"empty": true}`.

Here's a simplistic failing test that illustrates what I mean:

```java
  @Autowired
  private ObjectMapper mapper;

  @Test
  public void testSerializeEmptyTable() throws Exception {
    Table<String, Locale, String> testTable = HashBasedTable.create();
    String result = mapper.writeValueAsString(testTable);
    Assertions.assertNotNull(result);
    Assertions.assertEquals("{}", result);
  }
```

Result:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :{}
Actual   :{"empty":true}
```

I'm using a custom deserializer for this object (deserialization isn't supported natively as yet, only serialization -- seems odd, but true -- see [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatypes-collections/issues/1))

I suppose I could edit the custom deserializer to handle this case... but that seems like a poor, hack-y workaround. Is there a configuration or something I'm missing somewhere to help resolve this? Or is it perhaps a bug in the serializer?

Here's the dependency in my pom for reference:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-datatype-guava</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```